# Implementing j_security_check bypass

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, j-security-check

I have an application based on JSF 2.2 with Primefaces, that uses j_security_check to authenticate users. The application is doing well, but we have a situation, where other applications can authenticate the same user. The problem is, that this others applications doesn't run at the same server, and they use a "Fake Single Sign On" based on a token generated by a service. Each application receive this token, validate it, and confirms the user login or not.

What I am expecting to do, is receive this token, by a HTTP request, validate it, and auto-login the user in my application that uses j_security_check.

Anybody knows if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to perform programmatic login. You can do this anywhere you can get a hand to the `HttpServletRequest`, such as in a JSF backing bean, a servlet filter, or even a plain vanilla servlet.

```
request.login(username, password);
```

Note: this doesn't strictly "bypass" `j_security_check`. It **is** the programmatic variant of `j_security_check`.